# Identify invalid cell values in excel (using two sheets)

Tags: excel

Example data:

Sheet1:

```
PO      ID      AMT
PO1234  XYZ123  5
PO1234  XYZ123  10
PO9999  ABC123  4
PO1000  ABC123  8
```

Sheet2:

```
PO      ID      AMT
PO1234  XYZ123  5
PO1234  XYZ123  10
PO9999  ABC123  4
PO1000  ABC123  8
```

In Sheet2 I am able to achieve this result using:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A2:A5,Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!B2:B5,Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!C2:C5,Sheet2!C2)>0,"Valid","Not Valid")
```

what I would also like to be able to do is identify which cells are invalid:

```
PO      ID      AMT     
PO1234  XYZ124  5       Not Valid
PO1234  XYZ123  10      Valid
PO9997  ABC123  4       Not Valid
PO1000  ABC123  748     Not Valid
```

What I would also like to be able to do is identify which cells are invalid like below:

[Desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4xmJ.png)

Comment: how can we know if it's invalid? Based on yellow highlighting?

Comment: The IF(COUNTIFS) formula looks to see if each value is listed and returns Valid or Not Valid.  I highlighted the cells which are not valid in my example but I desire to do this automated with formulas.

Comment: Since they don't match I'm not sure how you identify when a individual cell is wrong unless there is a row to row relationship (i.e. supposed to have same values on same row). When one does match you know what row it's on for both sheets. In your example you have 3 invalid rows and it's not clear how you know which row should be used to measure 'invalid' results. Is there some other field that is unique AND consistent between both sources?

Comment: The comparison is row to row from Sheet1 to Sheet2.  If each field(cell) value by row exists then its valid, if not then its not valid, that is what the countifs is checking for.  Now with that being said the valid, and not valid work I just need to identify which field(cell) is the one causing invalid, could be more than one cell for example could be all cells in the row or just one cell.

Comment: In the picture I highlighted the cells that are in sheet2 that do not match values in sheet1 thus making the row "not valid"  That is manually done but I want to be able to automate finding the cells that cause the row to be not valid. As mentioned could be 1 cell or multiple cells.

Comment: In your `example data`, the data from sheet1 and sheet2 are the same. In your third table, the data is different.  Where did the third table come from?

Answer (score 0):

If the data table on sheet2 is really your third table of data (the one that looks different), then, to identify the differing cells it's merely a matter of using conditional formatting to format them with a yellow fill.

In other words, the CF formula on sheet2 would be:

```
=A2<>Sheet1!A2
```

And the **applies to** would be (given your table): `$A$2:$C$5`